# Best books to study sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm looking for a very specific book in algebraic geometry. I'm studying in this moment sheaves and I'm searching books with detailed proofs and explanations in this part. Almost every book I read in this field doesn't have for example that if $F$ is a pre-sheaf, then $F^+$ is a sheaf with a detailed proof.

Then what's the best book to study sheaves?

Thanks.

Comment: "Sheaves do not belong to algebraic geometry" - Tom Leinster ([link](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~tl/sheaves.pdf))

Comment: @ZevChonoles very interesting!

Comment: Try reading the second chapter of Vakil's FOAG notes. Good reference.

Comment: Görtz and Wedhorn's "Algebraic Geometry I".

Comment: There are no good books which explain this in detail (OK, a counterexample is Bosch's *Commutative Algebra and Algebraic Geometry*) because this is a good exercise. If you cannot solve it, don't proceed in the theory.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg very motivating!

Comment: Dear user 42912,I warmly recommend the very detailed exposition in Tennison's book mentioned [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/475355/3217). This book is the best introductory text to sheaves and is regrettably underappreciated.